# Power Series Representation...

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I am having a hard time understanding how to proceed with this question...
Find a power series representation for the function and determine it's radius of convergence

$$ f(x)= x^2\ln(1+x^2) $$

How should I start it out?

Comment: Find the power series for $\ln(1+x^2)$ first. You might find the power series for $1/(1-x)$ helpful.

Comment: This is what confuses me... How do I change that into a form of $$ 1/(1-x) $$ The derivative is $$ 2x/(1+x^2) $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Take the power series of $\log(1+y)$; replace $y$ by $x^2$; multiply the result by $x^2$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I think I get it... Let me try it out... Thanks

Comment: @StrugglingCalcStudent. You are welcome and you will get it !

Answer (score 2):

$$1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\tag{by the geometric series}$$

$$2x-2x^3+2x^5-\cdots=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

$$x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3}-\cdots=\ln(1+x^2)\tag{integrating from $0$ to $x$}$$

$$x^4-\frac{x^6}{2}+\frac{x^8}{3}-\cdots=x^2\ln(1+x^2)$$

Determining radius of convergence is pretty straightforward here.